# Create Random Invoice Generator

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a google sheet that contains a button that when clicked will create a random number in a particular column. However, I need the code to find the first empty cell in the column for the random number. The code I am currently using fills all the cells in the row verses one cell at a time when the button is clicked.

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [ {name:"Resubmit",functionName:"Resubmit"} ];
  sheet.addMenu("Script", entries);
};

function Resubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  cell.setValue( Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1) );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be more specific and give it a number of cells you want, [as per docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns):

```
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append after the last row either by setting cell like this:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
```

or by changing the function to this:

```
function Resubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");;
  sheet.appendRow([Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1)])
};
```